# consulta sql para estadisticas sobre sorteos de apuestas

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, ms-access

```
select distinct NUMERO, IIF(ISNULL(SUM(contador)),0,FORMAT(SUM(contador),'#####')) as VECES_10 from (
select fecha, n1 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n2 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n3 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n4 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n5 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc))
group by numero order by 2 desc, 1
UNION select distinct Numero, 0 as Contador from numeros
where numero not in (
select Numero from (
select fecha, n1 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n2 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n3 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n4 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)
UNION
select fecha, n5 AS Numero, 1 AS Contador from resultados where fecha in (select top 10 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc)))
group by numero
ORDER BY 2 DESC , 1;
```

En la consulta de arriba muestra los numeros que más salen de los últimos 10 sorteos pero no se como hacer para las parejas que mas aparecen no sé ni como empezar, gracias.
tengo una tabla (resultados) con las columnas (fecha,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,e1,e2) con los resultados de euromillon, no se como hacer una consulta para sacar las parejas de numeros que más se repiten y los trios, alguien me puede ayudar, gracias por todo.

---

Gracias pero no funciona la consulta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: busca "GROUP BY" y "COUNT"

Comment: gracias, si lo he intentado pero no tengo ni idea de como montarla, si quieres paso algunas que consegui

Comment: Sí, aquí las preguntas deberían indicar qué has intentado y qué problemas te has encontrado, lee [ask], [faq] y lo que es un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo asi, no se si esta bien la sintaxys pero ahi va la idea.

```
select * from (
select count(*) conteo, n1 pos1,n2 pos2 from resultados group by n1,n2 
union all
select count(*),n3,n4 from resultados group by n3,n4 
union all
select count(*),n5,n6 from resultados group by n5,n6 
) a order by a.conteo desc
```

Comment: Gracias Arnold pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

hay alguna otra forma de simplificar el codigo de abajo para mejorar el rendimiento de la consulta y no sea tan extensa ya que es solamente para los numeros de la columna n1 con el resto de columnas

```
select count(*) as conteo, n1 as pos1,n2 as pos2 from resultados where fecha in (select top 50 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc) group by n1,n2 order by 1 desc,2,3
union all
select count(*) as conteo, n1 as pos1,n3 as pos2 from resultados where fecha in (select top 50 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc) group by n1,n3 order by 1 desc,2,3
union all
select count(*) as conteo, n1 as pos1,n4 as pos2 from resultados where fecha in (select top 50 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc) group by n1,n4 order by 1 desc,2,3
union all
select count(*) as conteo, n1 as pos1,n5 as pos2 from resultados where fecha in (select top 50 fecha from resultados order by fecha desc) group by n1,n5 order by 1 desc,2,3;
```